# Converting normal path into uri path so that it can be used for mediametadataretriever?Can a normal path be used as uri?

Tags: android, file, media

first of all i am a newvie,i wanna know what to set as uri in the mediametadataretriever??
can i set it as metaRetriever.setDataSource(files[i].getName());if not what is the way to convert normal path into uri path??

what should i  replace this (files[i].getName()) with ????

here is the code

```
public ArrayList<SongDetails> getSongsFromDirectory(File f)
        {MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            ArrayList<SongDetails> songs = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();
            if (!f.exists() || !f.isDirectory()) 

            {    
                return songs;
            }
            File[] files = f.listFiles(new Mp3Filter());
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
            { 
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(files[i]);
                //mmr.setDataSource(null, uri);

            if (files[i].isFile()){ 
            SongDetails detail=new SongDetails(); 
            detail.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 

            detail.setSong(files[i].getName()); 
            //detail.setArtist(mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST)); 
            //detail.setAlbum(mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM)); 
            songs.add(detail); 
            }else if (files[i].isDirectory()){ 
            songs.addAll(getSongsFromDirectory(files[i])); 
            } 

            }

            return songs;



    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```
    File [] files = ... // your initialized variable

    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(files[i]);

        mmr.setDataSource(this, uri);
        String artist = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
        // More code, do something with the metadata, etc...
    }

    mmr.release();
```

Comment: and how can i use cursor in this so that i make up a database ,so that it does't have to load again and again

Comment: I don't understand your updated question. You just incorporated the code from my answer, your question is the same.

Comment: what should be the context??here

Comment: mmr.setDataSource(null, uri);

Comment: Are you calling this from within an activity? The "this" keyword refers to the current Activity context. If you don't want to use that approach you can probably use mmr.setDataSource(files[i].getPath()); instead.

Comment: You wouldn't use a cursor in this code. Cursor is used to retrieve results from a database.

Comment: Use mmr.setDataSource(getActivity(), uri);

Comment: yeah i know,but someone had a similar problem and someone suggested using a cursor,to setup a database for the scaled images  , so that the loading becomes faster or something like that.

Comment: so there are 2 ways of going aruound this

either i can use URI.......
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(files[i]);
          mmr.setDataSource(getActivity(), uri);

.....
or  i can use mmr.setDataSource(files[i].getPath());???i was using getfile earlier,maybe that was making the app to not respond

Comment: I answered your original question. You are now asking me to write an answer to another non-specific question. If you want help I don't suggest using this approach. If my answer helped, mark it, and create another question if you have one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035670/what-does-cursor-exactly-dohow-can-i-use-it-in-a-music-app

Comment: hey there is one more question i asked